# multiply of cordic issue

Tags: math, cordic

this is cordic multiply function I got a code when I run across from internet.
But It's quite a bit different from expected data.
How to modify to have this code with correctness?

## update code

```
 for (i=1; i=<8; i++)
 { 
  if (x > 0) {
   x = x - pow(2,-i);
   z = z + y*pow(2,-i);
   }
   else{
   x = x + pow(2,-i);
   z = z - y* pow(2,-i);
  }
```

If I do run with  x=7, y=8 then z=7.000 not 56.

What is the wrong point?

## update2

I got the right answer  but Thnaks, I have checked the range it works. Bytheway, is there any extension range algorithm? How to make range extension?

Comment: The above code does not even compile - please copy and paste the *actual* code. Please also format the code properly, as a courtesy to your readers.

Comment: The posted code is *still* broken - please *test* it before posting to make sure that it at least compiles. Also note that using `pow` pretty much defeats the whole purpose of a CORDIC multiply. `2^i` should be implemented using shifts.

Comment: @PaulR As you already know that what if I use shift then it does not  floating type.  (Int)2>>i

Comment: @PaulR would you let me know what should I do for instead of using pow(2,-i);?

Comment: You need to go back and read that paper more carefully - the whole point of CORDIC is that it operates on one bit at a time - `2^-i` is just a particular bit.

Comment: @PaulR yes I understand it. But I need your help to implement 2^-i. How to convert properly  2^-i ?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question, with your actual code that you've written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you took this function from [this paper](http://www.siue.edu/~gengel/pdf/cordic.pdf) (without attribution!). The code is full of obvious typos, but if you read the paragraph below the function it says:

> This calculation assumes that **both x and y are fractional ranging from -1 to 1**. The algorithm is valid for other ranges as long as the decimal point is allowed to float. With a few extensions, this algorithm would work well with floating point data.

Take home message: always read the accompanying documentation for any code that you plan to use, especially if you don't understand how it works.

Comment: Thnaks,  I have checked the range it works. Bytheway,  is there any extension range algorithm? How to make range extension?

Comment: You can just normalise your values to the required range and handle the exponents separately, since this just requires addition.